# JSONException returns error " No value for Search"?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I practice in creating an app using a movie API.
The idea is :

1- user input the movie name .

2- take this name and putting it in a link form like:

**Constants.URL_LEFT + *searchTerm* + Constants.URL_RIGHT + Constants.API_KEY**

And here I have two probabilities:

1- the input word are correct and match a movie name e.g ("Batman"), then every thing is right.

2- the input word are incorrect e.g ("Bamtan"), then I have error message 
"No value for search"

Note :

1- I try to use onErrorResponse() method but it works in noInternetConnection  only!

2- I try to solve the problem using try/catch , My App stayed in the catch area!

**My Question is :** 
How could I handle the incorrect input (Wrong URL)?

Here is my code for that :

```
public List<Movie> getMovies(final String searchTerm){
    movieList.clear();

    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Constants.URL_LEFT + searchTerm + Constants.URL_RIGHT + Constants.API_KEY,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");
                        for (int i = 0 ; i < moviesArray.length() ; i++){
                            JSONObject movieObj = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(movieObj.getString("Title"));
                            movie.setYear(" Released on : " + movieObj.getString("Year"));
                            movie.setMovieType("Type : " + movieObj.getString("Type"));
                            movie.setPoster(movieObj.getString("Poster"));
                            movie.setImdbId(movieObj.getString("imdbID"));

                            movieList.add(movie);
                        }
                        // notify the adapter for changes! very important...
                        movieRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // app just save the exception and repeat it after that for correct values also!
                        if (e.getMessage().equals("No value for Search")){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can not find any movie with this name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            MainActivity.this.onRestart();
                            popupDialog();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // dealing with losing network connection
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error Found!")
                    .setMessage("Make Sure you have a network Connection!")
                    .setCancelable(false);

            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Refresh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // re-check the internet connection!
                    getMovies(searchTerm);
                }
            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Exit!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // close the App!
                    finish();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    queue.add(objectRequest);
    return movieList;
}
```

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can try after `JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");`
if(moviesArray==null)
{ display the alert movie not found}else{ rest of your logic}

Comment: You can also check if Search is exist or not using  `JsonObj.has("Search")`

Comment: @GautamSurani I tried it also 
`response.has("Search");`
but didn't work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , Thanks to @Psypher and @GautamSurani for helping .

The problem fixed by:

1- Remove the new update of HAXM and install old version and create a new virtual Device.

2- update `if(moviesArray==null)` which I wrote above with `if (!response.has("Search"))` cause of response always having response!

**what I think**

The Emulator saves the last error value of SharedPreferences (Which entered by the user) and keep it on even if The user entered a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Check if moviesArray is null after `JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");`, if its null that would mean the search was not found and its not present in the json response and you can display your message saying movie is not found.

Below is how it looks with the changes

```
JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");
     if(moviesArray==null){
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can not find any movie with this name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
       else
      {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < moviesArray.length() ; i++){
        JSONObject movieObj = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle(movieObj.getString("Title"));
        movie.setYear(" Released on : " + movieObj.getString("Year"));
        movie.setMovieType("Type : " + movieObj.getString("Type"));
        movie.setPoster(movieObj.getString("Poster"));
        movie.setImdbId(movieObj.getString("imdbID"));

        movieList.add(movie);
    }
    // notify the adapter for changes! very important...
    movieRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your try . I'v tried it before and didn't work 

As you know compiler read from top to bottom, So it read
`JSONArray moviesArray = response.getJSONArray("Search");` 
if user entered wrong name , JSONException  will be thrown and the condition will never be checked!

Comment: can you post the movie not found json response

Comment: response from browser 
**{"Response":"False","Error":"Movie not found!"}**

json response 
**org.json.JSONException: No value for Search**

Comment: if you need to take a look at the project , github link for it :

[link](https://github.com/MuhamadJalal/MovieDetails)

Comment: Try this, before moviesArray declaration add this: `if(!response.has("Search")){ display error message} else ur logic`

Comment: I try it but didn't work 
when I enter a correct movie name returns `{ display error message}`

Comment: app save the last value for SharedPreferences

Comment: and I'm sure that i set SharedPreferances to update automatically

Comment: it used in onCreate method and hold the value of search word